# Locus with respect to two intersecting lines

Tags: analytic-geometry, locus

Find locus of a point moving between two lines $ x= \pm y\, \tan \alpha $ so that ratio of distances to them is a constant $= e$

Comment: That means $d_2 = d_1 + e$?

Comment: $d_1=d_2\,e$ as ratio.

Comment: By $d_1$ and $d_2$ do you mean $\inf\{\lVert (x_p-y\tan\alpha,y_p-y)\rVert\,:\,y\in\Bbb R\}$ and $\inf\{\lVert (x_p+y\tan\alpha,y_p-y)\rVert\,:\,y\in\Bbb R\}$ respectively?

Comment: These are lengths of normals dropped from the point on to these lines.

Comment: Just bash it? Assume coordinates and take ratios of their distances, doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance between a point $(u,v)$ and a line $l:ax+by-c=0,$ in the sense of the length of the perpendicular from $(u,v)$ to $l,$ is given by
$$d=\frac{|au+bv-c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}. \tag{1}$$

In your case the two lines have $a=1,b=\pm \tan \alpha.$ So on putting $d_1=d_2 \cdot e,$ the denominators in (1) cancel, and we get $$|x+\tan\alpha y|=e \cdot |x-\tan \alpha y| \tag{2}$$ (or the $+,-$ here are switched).

Now we consider signs for the sides of (2), and see the locus is a line.

Comment: So simply connect the point  to the origin, Right?

Comment: Narisimham-- I'm fairly sure my steps above are OK, and if so the line would be that connecting the origin to the point as you suggest.

Comment: Yes, sure Ok  and accepted also.